# Return resolve only on download complete [ http.get + Promise ]

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, download

Below is my code and I am trying to return only when the downloading of a file gets finished. But the request hangs even if download completes.

```
const download = async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        let file = fs.createWriteStream('./20181221001417.zip');
        http.get('http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db', (response) => {
           response.pipe(file);
        });
        file.on('finish', () => resolve('hi'));
    });
}
```

Any suggestion would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate you code here? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841480/how-to-fetch-the-image-files-from-a-server-and-zip-it-in-sailsjs/55956608#55956608

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine though :). In this case the writeStreamObject should be the name including the path of the file where you want to save the stream data.
From you code, it looks like you want to zip the file once the response has been successfully piped into the stream.

You can put the following code in a js file and execute it using `node.js`, it will download the image file into the zip directory. After that it zips that zip directory and names it `file.zip`.

> Blockquote If you run this snippet make sure you have a zip directory available in your current directory where this snippet is going to reside. otherwise you may get error. You can give your choice of path simply adding the path to `path.join` for example `path.join(__dirname, "your_path", "filename.extension")`.Sometimes the extension also matters, so be careful with that! In my case I had a jpeg file that I wanted to download but providing a .png extension in the filestream object, it created broken image.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const zipDir = require('zip-dir');


const download = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'zip', 'image.jpg');
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    http.get('http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg', (response) => {
      response.pipe(file);
    });
    // on finish event resolve the promise
    writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
  });
}

function zipTheFile() {
  let zipPath = path.join(__dirname, "file.zip");
  let sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, "zip");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    zipDir(sourcePath, {
      saveTo: zipPath
    }, function (err, buffer) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve('done');
    });
  })
}

(async () => {
  await download().catch(err => console.log(err));
  await zipTheFile();
})();
```

For zipping the folder i have used [zip-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-dir) library

If you want to download the file from browser it's pretty straight forward. The idea is to put the above logic inside a Service in this case like `FileDownloadService`. Here `downloadAndZipFile` exactly does the same thing like first download the file and zip it. Afterwards it creates a `ReadStream` object and pipes it into the res which makes the browser to download the file.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/download', async function (req, res) {

  await FileDownloadService.downloadAndZipFile();

  var file = path.join(__dirname, "file.zip")
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  // the name for file to be saved
  const fileName = "myzipFile"

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
module.exports = router;
```